# What are the clans of Shakuni, Raja Drupad, & Rani Madri in the Mahabharata?

Tags: mahabharata, genealogy

I know that the Pāṇḍavas were from the Kuru clan (vaṃśá) and Śrī Kṛṣṇa was from the Yadu clan, but from which clans did Shakuni, Raja Drupad, & Rani Madri come?

Comment: There may be a possibility of closing this question due  to its broadness. Narrow down it if possible.